# messed with my audio settings and now I can't record sound while recording my monitor

Tags: sound

I'm need to record a program that has sound to put together training material for work, so I decided to download SimpleScreenRecorder for the job.

I was able to record video seamlessly but the audio was messed up. I could hear the audio of the program but there were screeching and static noises over it. I thought maybe I left my mic connected to the computer and that was the source of the problem but the mic wasn't connected.

I started messing with my audio settings (**NO idea** what I did) and now I can only record video.

I installed PulseAudio and it confirmed that no sound is being recorded.

The audio entry in SimpleScreenRecorder is set to ALSA Default source. I did mess with those settings and now I know it was a stupid thing to do, so I changed it back to default but I still can't record audio.

If anyone could please help me figure out what's happening it would be great. I use Ubuntu because of my job so I'm not very well versed in it, but I can follow basic instructions in order to get more info.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, audio adapter HDA-Intel - HDA Intel, it that helps.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Some info [HERE](http://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/troubleshooting/)

Make sure the audio device is Pulse

Try this Pulse Audio Volume Control [HERE](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol/)

PulseAudio info [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581128/what-is-the-relation-between-alsa-and-pulseaudio-sound-architecture)

Try uninstalling and reinstalling, open terminal and enter:

```
sudo apt-get purge simplescreenrecorder
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

ENTER

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder
```

ENTER

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder
```

ENTER

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install simplescreenrecorder
```

ENTER