# How to disable Ubuntu's auto-volume adjuster?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I'm working on an audio project that requires the microphone gain to remain constant.

However, by default, Ubuntu seems to use some sort of dynamic microphone gain adjuster, so if the microphone registers a volume that's too loud, it reduces the gain.

This is breaking my project, because if a sudden loud sound occurs, Ubuntu reduces the gain to a point where the audio afterwards is too quiet for my application to hear.

Comment: Until you get a better answer from someone who knows what they are talking about: I think the optionally installable "pavucontrol" (PulseAudio Volume Control) package is a good candidate to look at in hopes for a solution. Other than that, browse documentation on "alsamixer" and "pulseaudio". They are the most important pieces in the Ubuntu sound department. https://askubuntu.com/questions/581128/what-is-the-relation-between-alsa-and-pulseaudio-sound-architecture | https://askubuntu.com/questions/426983/how-can-i-tell-if-im-using-alsa-or-pulse-audio-by-default-switching-to-i3-wm

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/q/689209/349837) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/279407/349837) answer your question?

Comment: @PabloBianchi No. Those talk about stopping an application from adjusting the gain. I'm talking about ALSA/PulseAudio itself from doing it (or whatever is behind Sound Settings dialog).

Answer (score 0):

I think the Sound Settings application itself is what's doing the dynamic gain adjustment. I've found if I just open it, set the volume gain to 100%, and then close it before it has a change to adjust, my application runs fine. It's only a problem when I leave Sound Settings open that it screws up the gain.